# Nginx need to edit etc/hosts file

Tags: nginx

I using docker-compose to run python app, In that I have a service as nginx. Currently I am using `server_name localhost;` and it is running fine. Now instead of localhost I am trying to use domain name eg `www.example.com` on my local system. So I edited nginx conf as `server_name www.example.com`. It didnot worked, On googling I found that I need to add this name to `/etc/hosts` file. I found few egs as below:

-A

```
127.0.0.1 localhost www.example.com
```

-B

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 www.example.com
```

I am new to devOps.

Questions:

1. Is it mandatory to edit `/etc/hosts` file. Can we achieve without this?
2. Which way is preferred way A or B?
3. After doing above stuff, If I want to deploy on cloud, Do I need to configure anything more with respect to domain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ususally you should use DNS, not `hosts` file.

To access the web sites by one of the [server_name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html), you need to configure hosts file on you local machine, more precisely, the machine where you are running the web browser. If it's your Windows laptop, this is `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, which usually maps to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`. In this file you should have an entry like:

```
192.168.1.123 www.example.com
```

Where `192.168.1.123` is the IP of your web server. Make sure that IP is reachable from your web browser machine.